# how to recognise Single tap using UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using `UIWebView` to show a pdf file in my `MainViewController`. On single tap I want to load a new View to the `MainViewController`.

But the UIWebView is not allowing default UITouch event

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

}
```

How to solve this problem?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally webView userInteractionEnabled should be set to NO and on top of the web view that is the view controller. We can use a TapGesture which will load another view.

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView a is subclass of UIScrollView.
You can use touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView: method defined in UIScrollView [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html).

You need to define this method in your UIWebView own class:

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inContentView:(UIView *)view {
// DO SOMETHING
return NO;}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Pierre

Thanks

I did the following :

```
@implementation UIViewTouch

. . .

- (BOOL)touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inContentView:(UIView *)view 
{
    // DO SOMETHING
    return NO;
}
```

In the view controller implementation:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 1000);     
    UIViewTouch *viewTouch = [[UIViewTouch alloc]initWithFrame:frame];

    NSString *urlAddress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"page1" ofType:@"pdf"];  
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [viewTouch loadRequest:requestObj]; [self.view addSubview:viewTouch];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `UIView` sub class containing the whole `UIWebView`. Then the event `hitTest` will be fired on touching the webview. 
Note: Don't put anything to the container except the webView.

```
@interface myWebViewContainer : UIView
... ...
@end
```

Then override the hitTest event:

```
-(UIView*) hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Hit test %@", [event description]);
    UIView * returnView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    [delegate userDidTapWebView];// notify the delegate that UIWebView is being touched by some naughty user :P


    return  returnView;
}
```